# JOINING 2 QUERIES

Tags: sql, database, sql-query-store

I have a query which gives me results based in my where condition (a varchar e.g. 20200227Abc).

I run a union of those query with same query but changing the Where condition to (20200126xyz).

I want if the data is present for both where conditions only then give me the result of first query where (20200227abc).

Please advise.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow, please add some code as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to help get a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking to get the results for Condition 1 only when it satisfies condition 2 as well. You could use exists in this case. Using a sample:

```
;with cte as
(select 1 as id,'20200227Abc' as val union
select 1 as id,'20200126xyz' as val union
select 2 as id,'20200227Abc' as val)

select * 
from cte a
where val='20200227Abc' and 
    exists (select 1 from cte b where b.val='20200126xyz' and a.id=b.id)
```

This should give you the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.val = '20200227Abc' or
      (t.val = '20200126xyz' and
       not exists (select 1 from t where t.val = '20200227Abc')
      );
```